# Accessing a page only once using php

Tags: php

I just created an attendance management system. Now I want the user to add the attendance only once a day, and restrict them if they try to do it again. How would i do that? And is there any example to start with? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp on your database. Check timestamp from database if user add the attendance before saving into the database.